# Глобальная область видимости в PHP

Tags: php, замыкания, область-видимости

У меня появилась проблема с глобальной областью видимости. Я знаю что глобальные переменные это зло, но есть необходимость их использовать (Передавать их как аргумент не вариант).
Есть следующий код:

```
$conf = array();

function get_option($key){
   global $conf;
   var_dump($conf); // NULL
}
```

Однако, если сделать так:

```
global $conf;
$conf = array();

function get_option($key){
   global $conf;
   var_dump($conf); // work
}
```

То работает хорошо. Раньше `global` не добавлял и мог получить доступ до переменной.
Вопрос с чем это связано или как можно сделать, функция видела все глобальные переменные, которые объявлены в этом файле где и функция? Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: и что такое _"замыкания"_ в вашем вопросе?

Comment: Все таки не раскрыта тема, зачем вам нужно видеть __все__ глобальные переменные?

Comment: такой необходимости у вас нет. Просто вы не видите альтернатив. Наипростейшим(но не самым лучшим) вариантом будет сделать класс `Config` со статическими методами

Comment: @teran, https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/103983/

Comment: я бы сказал,что ваша проблема с первым кодом не воспроизводится в пхп 5.6 и 7.1

Comment: @tutankhamun, дополнил вопрос.

Comment: @Node_pro возможно, вам нужно передавать в функцию только один параметр? тогда можно использовать замыкание: `$conf = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

$get_option = function ($key) use ($conf) {
    return $conf[$key];
};

echo $get_option(1); // b`

Comment: @teran разве не воспроизводится? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/00064752dc484146a1ae8fdf4f38488b611a24e9

Comment: @teran, такой возможности больше нет в новых версиях? Я думал, что возможно в этом проблема

Comment: @АлексейШиманский https://ideone.com/sXSYsf хм

Comment: Хрустальный шар говорит что данный файл включается через `require` или `include` внутри другой функции. Поэтому переменные становятся локальными и не видны внутри определенной в этом файле функции

Comment: @Эдуард, спасибо за ответ. Я этот вариант тоже думал( жаль что он работает только с анонимными функциями). Но проект какой я сейчас делаю, содержит многое на глобальных переменных. До меня разработчик, какой с толкнулся с такой проблемой выкрутился след. образом. Он просто заново доставал их с БД

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вызывать функцию то не забыл? :)

Comment: @Node_pro по поводу замыканий, вам бы самому прочитать статью целиком. Если функция просто использует переменную из глобальной области видимости, это не замыкание. Замыкание это, например, когда возвращенная анонимная функция имеет доступ к той области видимости где она была определена, хотя тот код уже и был завершен.

Comment: @Node_pro дополнил ответ. Но так делать нельзя :)

Comment: добавьте-ка [mcve], а то пока что, повторюсь, https://ideone.com/sXSYsf

Comment: @Node_pro первый пример из вашего поста тоже работает. [См. пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b1ec01b9396c5ffc37fce6969c24437f0fd03f57)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция всегда может их видеть как элементы массива `$GLOBALS`. Но если вы очень хотите выстрелить себе в ногу четыре раза подряд, то вот рецепт:

```
extract($GLOBALS);
```

**Дополнено**

> ...с чем это связано...

С тем что у вас файл подключается в другом php-файле внутри функции - соответственно все определенные, вроде бы как глобально, переменные становятся локальными внутри той самой функции. Например:

```
// файл main.php
function main_func() {
    include 'my_functons.php';
}

// файл my_functions.php
$conf = array();

function get_option($key) {
    global $conf;
    // ...
}
```

Если вы будете подключать my_functions.php в глобальной области видимости - `$conf` будет глобальным, но в приведенном примере `$conf` - это локальная переменная внутри функции `main_func()`, поэтому `$conf` не видна внутри `get_option()` даже когда там написано `global $conf`

> ...как можно сделать, функция видела все глобальные переменные, которые объявлены в этом файле где и функция

Если отталкиваться от данной вами информации, то у вас все плохо и требуется достаточно глубокий рефакторинг. Относительно возникшей проблемы можете сделать так:

```
$conf = array();

global $meta_globals; // определяем массив для локальных переменных в глобальной видимости
$meta_globals = get_defined_vars(); // собираем локальные переменные

function get_option($key){
   extract($GLOBALS['meta_globals']); // переносим собранные переменные в другую функцию
   var_dump($conf);
}
```

**Disclaimer**

В указанных в вопросе условиях хорошего решения быть не может. Приведенное решение можно использовать только если в остальном все также плохо. **Не используйте этот код если у вас есть возможность сделать все по человечески**

Comment: у человека же написано "объявлены в этом файле где и функция", к чему эти фантазии про инклуды?

Comment: Почему фантазии? "Раньше global не добавлял и мог..." - отсюда однозначный вывод - include раньше был глобальным - теперь стал локальным. Есть другие идеи как глобально определенная в файле переменная могла скрыться из глобальной области видимости?

Comment: опечаткой в имени переменной? :) про инклуды в вопросе просто ничего нет. так что вопрос к качеству самого вопроса